# Bottom navigation not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

My bottom navigation view not working. When i click on items my fragment in not loading.

`beginTransaction()` may produce **NullPointerException**.

This is my Activity :

```
public static void enableNavigation(Context context, final BottomNavigationViewEx view, final FragmentManager supportFragmentManager){
    view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragment = new FragmentMarker();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_bookmark:
                    fragment = new FragmentBookmark();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_blog:
                    fragment = new FragmentBlog();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_notification:
                    fragment = new FragmentNotification();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_account:
                    fragment = new FragmentAccount();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;

            }
           return false;
        }

        private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            // load fragment
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

And this is one of my fragments :

```
 private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: Setting up BottomNavigationView");
    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = getView().findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(getContext(), bottomNavigationViewEx, getFragmentManager());
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be getting `NullPointerException` because you are trying to access a fragment's fragment manager before it has been allocated to one in the first place.

So, you need to use the one provided by the activity. So inside your `loadFragment` method do the following:

Before:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            // load fragment
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

After:

```
 private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
                // load fragment
                FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
```

Comment: `BottomNavigationViewHelper.this` cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Just looked at your code again and noticed that your enableNavigation() method provides you with a FragmentManager instance called "supportFragmentManager". Please use this instead of calling getFragmentManager()

Comment: still `BottomNavigationViewHelper.this` cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: I've updated my answer code to demonstrate what I meant in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
 * with this fragment's activity.  Note that this will be non-null slightly
 * before {@link #getActivity()}, during the time from when the fragment is
 * placed in a {@link FragmentTransaction} until it is committed and
 * attached to its activity.
 *
 * <p>If this Fragment is a child of another Fragment, the FragmentManager
 * returned here will be the parent's {@link #getChildFragmentManager()}.
 */
@Nullable
final public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
    return mFragmentManager;
}
```

Your fragmentmanger returns null if you try to get fragmentmanager from fragment that is not attched to activity. So change your code

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

**To**

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: getFragmentManager() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Remove static class of enablenaviogation from your code. `public static void enableNavigation(Context context,......)`  change to `public void enableNavigation(Context context,......)`

Comment: class must be static because i am using this library https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx